# How can a POS terminal determine if a coupon is valid?

Tags: database, point-of-sale, coupon

This is something I have always wondered about. Coupons can be very touchy when it comes to their requirements, like:

- Expiration date
- Item quantity requirements
- Which items are eligible
- Can involve multiple groups of items (e.g., "Buy X number of items from this group, get an item from another group free/money off/percent off")

I know that the GS1 DataBar can hold a lot more information like this, but I'd imagine that only goes so far.

How does a POS terminal determine whether a scanned coupon is valid or not? Is some kind of supplemental information stored in a database somewhere?